# Adding a Javascript onClick event to a HTML checkbox has prevented me from 'unchecking' the checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Here is my function

```
function toggleCheckbox (element) {
  if(document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = true) {
                            document.getElementById("strAPISuccessURL").value = "http://www.gladstonebrookes.co.uk/thank-you/";
            }
  else {
      document.getElementById("strAPISuccessURL").value = "http://www.gladstonebrookes.co.uk/the-call/";
  }  
}
```

and the function is called on a checkbox onClick event

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" onchange="toggleCheckbox(this)" />
```

The default value for the form input field is as follows

```
<input type="hidden" name="strAPISuccessURL" id="strAPISuccessURL" value="http://www.gladstonebrookes.co.uk/the-call/" />
```

When I click the checkbox the value of the input with id="strAPISuccessURL" changes as it should. The problem I am having is that I am then unable to 'uncheck' the box so that the URL reverts back to the original.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a single `=` in your `if`. This is setting the value to `true` then returning `true` and not "checking" if it is `true` and returning that.

You most likely want to use `===`

```
if (document.getElementById("checkbox").checked === true) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It's been a long day! Can't believe I missed that, thanks for the quick reply! Everything now working as it should :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have used `=` instead of `==`, you can also Try this,

```
if(element.checked) {
   document.getElementById("strAPISuccessURL").value = "http://www.gladstonebrookes.co.uk/thank-you/";
}else{
  document.getElementById("strAPISuccessURL").value = "http://www.gladstonebrookes.co.uk/the-call/";
}
```